# How Can I write UART function without vsnprintf

Tags: stm32, uart

How can I use Serialdebug function without vsnprintf or args. I want to use just

```
  HAL_UART_Transmit function to print my string.
```

instead of this function:

```
void Serialdebug(const char *serial_data, ...)
{
  char uartbuffer[1024]="";
  va_list arg;
  va_start(arg, serial_data);
  uint16_t len = vsnprintf(uartbuffer, 1024, serial_data, arg);
  va_end(arg);
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t *)uartbuffer, len, 100);

}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: write your own prinf  function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can basically reduce the function to a call to `HAL_UART_Transmit`:

```
void Serialdebug(const char *str)
{
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t *)str, strlen(str), 100);
}
```

Comment: When I use like this I cant print my parameter like:
Serialdebug("my param %d",myparam)
return to me "my param %d"

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question. It sounded as if you didn't want to output a string and not provide any arguments. `vsnprintf` is the core function responsible for formatting strings with `%d` and similar options. So if you want string formatting, there's hardly anyway around it. Can you better describe what you really want to achieve or what problem you have?